# Can't pass the variable to subject in email laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

```
 Mail::send('emails.cont',['name'=>$n,'email'=>$email],function($message){
        $message->to('abc@gmail.com','efe')->from('cde@gmail.com')->subject($s);
    });
```

There for the subject, I am trying to pass a variable called $s which contains a value which defined there. But, it will underlying in red and saying undefined variable called $s. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try the following code

```
Mail::send('emails.cont',['name'=>$n,'email'=>$email],function($message) use ( $s ) {
        $message->to('abc@gmail.com','efe')->from('cde@gmail.com')->subject($s);
    });
```

Comment: Then it will display following exception.  Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}()

Comment: There for the from part, the given email is not taken which means it is not over written the mail.php email address. Do you know how to solve that?